# ¿Cómo crear una carpeta con async?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, uwp

Estoy intentando crear un programa en C# y UWP que cree una carpeta. Estoy usando el void de forma async. He probado varias formas pero no encuentro nada que me sirva.
Usé esto:

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        FileOpenPicker fileDialog = new FileOpenPicker();
        fileDialog.ViewMode = PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
        fileDialog.SuggestedStartLocation = PickerLocationId.PicturesLibrary;
        fileDialog.FileTypeFilter.Add("*");

        IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> files = await fileDialog.PickMultipleFilesAsync();

        foreach (StorageFile file in files)
        {
            var messageDialog = new MessageDialog(Path.GetDirectoryName(file.Path));
            await messageDialog.ShowAsync();
            await Task.Run(() => Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(file.Path)));
        }
    }
```

Además, me da este código de error:

> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: 'Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users'.'

¿Alguna solución? Busqué otras preguntas en este foro pero no me resolvieron el problema. Gracias.

Comment: Pero tu problema es que no podes crear un directorio? porque Users es un directorio del sistema. Estas queriendo crear directorios con el nombre de los archivos dentro de un directorio?

Comment: No, intento crear un directorio en la misma ubicación donde se encuentra un archivo.